# Sql query with SET and LIKE showing incorrect results

Tags: sql-server

Table

```
| patientFirstName | patientMiddleName | patientLastName |  startdate |    enddate |

|-------------------------|---------------------------|------------------------|--------------|------------|

|          Patient |              Demo |            Test | 2018-09-02 | 2018-09-08 |

|             John |               Doe |            Demo | 2018-09-02 | 2018-09-14 |

|            Admin |             Admin |           Admin | 2018-09-07 | 2018-09-20 |
```

When I run the below query I'm expecting just a single record i.e "Patient Demo Test" instead I'm getting two records. Where have I gone wrong?

```
DECLARE @searchInput varchar(10)
DECLARE @startTime DATE
DECLARE @endTime DATE
SET @searchInput = 'o'
SET @startTime = '2018-09-02'
SET @endTime = '2018-09-12'
SELECT * FROM PatientDemoTable
WHERE  (@startTime IS NULL OR startdate >= @startTime)
AND (@endTime IS NULL OR enddate <= @endTime)
AND patientFirstName like '%'+@searchInput+'%' 
OR patientMiddleName like '%'+@searchInput+'%'
OR patientLastName like '%'+@searchInput+'%'
```

When I remove

```
AND patientFirstName like '%'+@searchInput+'%' 
OR patientMiddleName like '%'+@searchInput+'%'
OR patientLastName like '%'+@searchInput+'%'
```

Proper record shows up but without the text filter.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/db4db5/5

Comment: Probably precedence of ANDs and ORs. Can you try putting brackets around the three OR clauses? Else you might be getting 'has an o in the first name and date match' or 'has an o in last name ignoring dates'

Comment: yup it worked !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add brackets where appropriate:

```
DECLARE @searchInput varchar(10)
DECLARE @startTime DATE
DECLARE @endTime DATE
SET @searchInput = 'o'
SET @startTime = '2018-09-02'
SET @endTime = '2018-09-12'
SELECT * FROM PatientDemoTable
WHERE  (@startTime IS NULL OR startdate >= @startTime)
AND (@endTime IS NULL OR enddate <= @endTime)
AND (patientFirstName like '%'+@searchInput+'%' 
OR patientMiddleName like '%'+@searchInput+'%'
OR patientLastName like '%'+@searchInput+'%')
```